# Unknown Terminals - Sourcing

Tags: circuit-design, identification, terminal

Does anyone have any info on the terminals shown in the photo below? I believe they are an old Siemens design, but I don't have a proper name to try to source these. There are no markings or numbers on them.

[image]

Comment: If you take some straight clear face photo of these, you might be able to do google image search, which is surprisingly smart these days.

Comment: Even if your managed to find a source, how do you know they are suitable for your needs? What information haven't you said that could be important here?

Comment: Siemens has made a gazillion products and retired even more.  Many of their parts are custom-made.  The chances of finding these anywhere except salvage, is very slim.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Andy aka - These are currently in use, but I need more for maintenance purposees. So I know they are suitable; the equipment has been running for decades. I'm sure I could use something else with a bit of redesign, but I thought maybe someone here would recognize them. 1000 eyes are better than 2...

Comment: have you checked the repair manual?

Comment: Those might be called "stab," "push-in" or "push" terminals. When you searched, did you included the name of the Siemens equipment? It might help to search "replacement terminals for Siemens 'whatsit'."